# How to know if my android device is connected to VoWIFI (Voice over Wifi)

Tags: java, android, wifi, telephonymanager, wifimanager

I'm developing an android application to get some information about the network. I use to work with TelephonyManager to get the network type where my device is connected to. I succed to get those information for 2G, 3G, 4G. Now I want to know if I'm connected to VoWIFI.

I've tried to look at the android documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiInfo.html 
to find out where to get this information but I wasn't able to find it.

What I did for 2G, 3G, 4G:

```
 public String getNetworkClass() {
        TelephonyManager mTelephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        int networkType = mTelephonyManager.getNetworkType();
        switch (networkType) {
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_GPRS:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_CDMA:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_1xRTT:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_IDEN:
                return "2G";
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_0:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_A:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSDPA:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSUPA:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPA:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_B:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EHRPD:
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPAP:
                return "3G";
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_LTE:
                return "4G";
            default:
                return "Unknown";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can detect if you application is connected to the internet like this

```
  public class Utility {
  public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
  }
  }
```

And then you call it in any activity like this

```
  Utility.isNetworkAvailable(AnyActivity.this);
```

Add those permission in your Manifest file

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Another fancy way is to create a BroadcastReceiver that listens to your connctivity status.

If you want to explore this approach more I can write an example for you.

Comment: Thank you for your response but I'm not interested in knowing my internet status. I want to know if I'm connected to VoWIFI or not.